# Getting the memory Error while manipulating the column in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, operation

i was working on a DataFrame 282 rows × 4 columns, i wanted to manipulate a particular column each element of the column should be multiplied by number 1000000, while performing this operation i am getting the Memory Error: can someone assist me to resolve this issue.

below is the operation i want to perform.

```
energy['Energy Supply']=energy['Energy Supply']*1000000
```

**Error message:-"MemoryError:"**

Comment: What's the value in `energy['Energy Supply']`

Comment: I found, while reading the Excel file, Header and footer has also been included, can it be the reason i am getting the Memory Error ?

Comment: If the datatype isn't float or int, it will copy the string that many times

Comment: I removed the header and footer while reading the file,(pd.read_excel("Energy Indicators.xls",header=16,skipfooter=38).now i could manipulate the column it worked , Thank you so much for your help..